# Openshift webhook branch filter

Tags: git, git-branch, webhooks, openshift-origin

I successfully installed Openshift Origin (latest), and performed automated builds.

I.e.,  once I pushed something on `master` branch, I get a build triggered through a git webhook, using the URL provided by Openshift triggers.

Now I would like to trigger a build only when a specific branch is updated.

I created a new `dev` branch, and added a new build with its dedicated service and route.

But when I push in `master`, the `dev` build is also triggered. The same occurs for `master` when I push in `dev`, though I updated `Source ref:` with the correct branch name.

However, `master` build uses the `master` branch, and `dev` build is done with `dev` branch. But I want only the `dev` build to be triggered when I push in `dev` branch only.

Here is the YAML output of the following command : `oc get buildconfigs lol-master --output=yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
  creationTimestamp: 2016-04-22T06:02:16Z
  labels:
    app: lol-master
  name: lol-master
  namespace: lol
  resourceVersion: "33768"
  selfLink: /oapi/v1/namespaces/lol/buildconfigs/lol-master
  uid: c3d383c3-084f-11e6-978b-525400659b2e
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: lol-master:latest
      namespace: lol
  postCommit: {}
  resources: {}
  source:
    git:
      ref: master
      uri: http://git-ooo-labs.apps.10.2.2.2.xip.io/ooo/lol.git
    secrets: null
    type: Git
  strategy:
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: ruby:latest
        namespace: openshift
    type: Source
  triggers:
  - github:
      secret: cd02b3ebed15bc98
    type: GitHub
  - generic:
      secret: 7be2f555e9d8a809
    type: Generic
  - type: ConfigChange
  - imageChange:
      lastTriggeredImageID: centos/ruby22-centos7@sha256:990326b8ad8c4ae2619b24d019b7871bb10ab08c41e9d5b19d0b72cb0200e28c
    type: ImageChange
status:
  lastVersion: 18
```

Am I missing something ?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of where I could learn to `"add a new build with its dedicated service and route"` - I'm also wanting to create a "development version" of an OpenShift application, but not sure how to start.  I thought I would just have to create another project in OpenShift just for dev (maybe "clone" the production app?), create a `"development"` branch in GitHub, and modify the new project's build config to use the `"development"` branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an issue on Github related to this behavior ([GitHub issue #8600](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/8600)). I've been said I need to use a Github webhook, and not a generic webhook in this case.

I switched the webhooks to github type, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You're pointing to master branch in your BuildConfig:

```
 source:
    git:
      ref: master
      uri: http://git-ooo-labs.apps.10.2.2.2.xip.io/ooo/lol.git
    secrets: null
    type: Git
```

but should rather point to `dev`, as you're saying. Generally you need separate BC for the `master` and `dev` branches and each will have the webhook configured accordingly. Additionally the format for the branch is `refs/heads/dev`, since that's the information OpenShift gets from github.

In the [code](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/a1079aa65ea3f0b23d4820a15707218182e33e84/pkg/build/webhook/github/github.go#L71) we're checking for matching branches and ignore the hook if it doesn't match. Please check once again, and if you're still experiencing problem I'd ask you to open a bug against https://github.com/openshift/origin with detailed description.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried using format  `ref/heads/dev`, but I get the following error in log `Error: build error: error: pathspec 'refs/heads/dev' did not match any file(s) known to git.`. By the way, build has run also on prod and master env. I will try to open a bugrequest on GitHub.